# abelian subgroups of SL(n,Q_p)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, buildings

Does anyone know where I can find a classification of abelian subgroups of SL(n,Q_p) isomorphic to (Q_p)^{n-1} up to conjugacy?

Even for n=2, it would be very useful.  For example, over R, there are three 1 dimensional groups up to conjugacy: orthogonal, diagonal, and unipotent. But the orthogonal group is of course isomorphic to S^1, not to R.   Over Q_p, the answer should be similar: SL_n (Z_p) (compact), unipotent, and diagonal.  However, I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: How is $SL_2(Z_p)$ abelian?

Comment: Hint: Let $k$ be a field. In the algebra of 2 by 2 matrices over $k$ what can the centralizer of an element be? The answer is related to degree two extension fields. The generalizable thing about $SO(2)$ is not that it is compact but that it corresponds to a group of complex numbers.

Comment: And a further request-for-clarification: presumably you mean (at least) closed topological subgroups, not (only) algebraic subgroups defined over $\mathbb Q_p$, and not arbitrary subgroups?

Comment: @paulgarrett: The question reduces to finding the *maximal* abelian subgroups. Such a subgroup must be equal to its centralizer, hence algebraic.

Comment: Yes, in particular I am interested in subgroups isomorphic to (Q_p) ^{n-1}

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Where can I find a reference for the classification of maximal abelian subgroups?

Comment: @ArielleLeitner: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Arielle, you ask about groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p^{n-1}$. Isomorphic as what? Abstarct groups, topological groups, algebraic groups? The answer will eventually be the same, I suppose, but the question style is quite different.

Comment: I suppose that the maximal abelian unipotent subgroups are the unipotent radicals of maximal parabolic subgroups. Those are $km$-dimensional where $k+m=n$.

Comment: In particular, for $n=2$ you get a unique conjugacy class and for $n=3$ you have two such.

Comment: @UriBader Hi Uri, I'm interested in isomorphism as abstract groups.  Maximal abelian unipotent subgroups are contained in (but not equal to) unipotent radicals of maximal parabolic subgroups.  In general the unipotent radical is not abelian.  For n=3 there are three conjugacy classes of maximal abelian unipotent subgroups.

Comment: Yes, Arielle, I agree, at least partially. I do think that radicals of maximal parabolics are maximal abelian, but there are other ones. Indeed, for $n=3$ you can get a third conjugation class.

Comment: @UriBader Uri, of course you are correct.  The unipotent radical of a maximal parabolic is abelian.  But in general the unipotent radical of a parabolic is not abelian.  There are maximal unipotent abelian subgroups which are not contained in the unipotent radical of a maximal parabolic.  The question is how to classify those.